# Windows XP Registry: I am looking for Screensaver.slideshow but it seems to be missing

Tags: windows, registry, key, settings, screensaver

I am attempting to programatically change the path that my screensaver slideshow looks for pictures. It is supposed to be in the registry path `HKCU\Control Panel\Screensaver.slideshow`. The `Screensaver.slideshow` folder is not there though. I have checked this on multiple computers but everywhere that I Google says that this should be the path.

Comment: Also, isn't that usually under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Screensavers`?

Comment: I am sorry. I just typed control panel for the path in my question. I am actually physically looking for it using regedit first. My problem is I am not seeing it anywhere. Also, I believe it depends on the system for the location. On XP, if i am reading correctly, then the location should be where I am posting. All of the other screensavers are there except "Screensaver.slideshow" and "Screensaver.flowerbox".

Comment: you do realize that people sometimes prune stuff from their systems which they consider as not adding any value to it? In particular on XP you have under "Add/Remove Programs" the option to remove Windows components (some aren't actually removed but disabled, others actually get removed). If I remember correctly screen savers are among those components. So basically the path doesn't exist. Big thing. Doesn't that just mean that your code should simply tell the user about it and not do whatever it would otherwise do?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand what you are saying. Are you saying I should check if this is installed/disabled? As for my code this is a company wide screensaver that I am trying to push out with the pictures being safety information. I was going to use Group Policy to manage this. That is why I actually need it to be there.

Answer (score 0):

This key initially does not exist. It is created after you change any of the slideshow settings.